# WSGI Segmentation Fault After Upgrade from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 on Debian Linux with Django

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

After running a dist-upgrade from debian 7.1 to 8.10, WSI seg faults with the following errors in the Apache logs:

```
[Tue Mar 27 21:06:34.843952 2018] [core:notice] [pid 117022] AH00052: child pid 128687 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Mar 27 21:06:34.844011 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 117022] mod_wsgi (pid=128687): Process 'icmlcc' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Tue Mar 27 21:06:34.844021 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 117022] mod_wsgi (pid=128687): Process 'icmlcc' terminated by signal 11
[Tue Mar 27 21:06:34.844030 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 117022] mod_wsgi (pid=128687): Process 'icmlcc' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Tue Mar 27 21:06:53.989780 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 128282] ssl_engine_io.c(1213): (70014)End of file found: [client 183.11.70.193:19265] AH02007: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]
```

I'm looking for any help I can get troubleshooting this. Thanks in advance. More info...

When I view the website in my browser, I'm presented with Django's Internal Server Error page, but the SSL certificate is correctly presented and trusted.

I occasionally receive, "Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process" in my site error.log

I'm using packages supplied by Debian for everything:

```
libapache2-mod-wsgi/oldstable,now **4.3.0-1** amd64 [installed]
apache2-bin/oldstable,now 2.4.10-10+deb8u11 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python2.7/oldstable,now 2.7.9-2+deb8u1 amd64 [installed]
```

The code works correctly with the development server. manage.py runserver works.

The relevant parts of my .conf file:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/icml.cc.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/icml.cc.key
#SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
SSLCACertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
<Directory /www/icml.cc/media>
  #Order deny,allow
  #Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /www/icml.cc/admin>
  #Order deny,allow
  #Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias / /www/icml.cc/djnipscc/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess icmlcc home=/var/www python-path=/home.local/lee/.virtualenvs/nips/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/www/icml.cc processes=25 threads=10 maximum-requests=0
WSGIProcessGroup icmlcc
```

I tried using a python that was compiled from source.  I haven't tried building mod_wsgi from source.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What Python distribution are you using? You can't use a Python distribution with mod_wsgi that isn't compiled with the same SSL libraries as Apache, when using mod_ssl. So if you use Anaconda Python, it will all fail dismally because it ships with its own SSL libraries.

Comment: Okay, you mention using ``python2.7/oldstable``. Question still is whether it was compiled with the same SSL libraries as Apache ``httpd`` was.

Comment: BTW, mod_wsgi 4.3.0 as used by Debian is quite old and shouldn't really be used. It isn't supported.

Comment: You should also set ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}``. The problem may be in a third party extension module for Python that doesn't work in Python sub interpreters. See http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Comment: mod_wsgi and apache are from a supported Debian.  My hope is that Debian handles security.  ./lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so-2.7
 linux-vdso.so.1 
 libpython2.7.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so.1.0 
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 
 libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 
 libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 
Does this look expected?

Comment: I have WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} in /etc/apahce2/apache.conf

Comment: You were correct in thinking the older version of mod_wsgi was the problem. I compiled the latest version from source code using http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-installation-guide.html and the problem is solved. Thanks Graham